# Can't find sObject in use

Tags: apex, api

I'm transferring code from a managed package to a new org.

This line of code

```
public static string getGeocodingAPIkey(String customSettingName) {
    Google_Geocoding_API__c goecodingCustomSetting = Google_Geocoding_API__c.getValues('Default');
    String geocodingAPIKey = goecodingCustomSetting.Geocoding_API_Key__c;
    return geocodingAPIKey;
}
```

There is the `Google_Geocoding_API__c` class. When I go to my list of custom sObjects in the managed package org, it's not there.

[image]

The error I'm getting is

> Invalid type: Google_Geocoding_API__c

Comment: It's a `Custom Setting`, not a `Custom Object`. If it's missing, then you need to create it...

Comment: @AdrianLarson is there anyway to know that when you look just at the code?

Comment: Yeah, it's the only way `getValues`, `getInstance`, or `getOrgDefaults` would ever work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sObjects (or Custom Settings) in a package you need the package prefix. Usually something like `packagename__Google_Geocoding_API__c`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_prefix.htm